# Assign a value to one of 2 properties depending on the if

Tags: c#, dry, simplify

Is it possible, in C#, to simplify this if by generalising the properties somehow? Really curious.

```
Image Crop = new Image("test.jpg");
int Margin = 2;
int Dif = Math.Abs(Crop.Width - Crop.Height);
if (Crop.Width < Crop.Height) {
    Crop.X -= Dif / 2;                //
    Crop.Width += Dif;                // A
    Dif = Crop.Height * Margin * 2;   //
} else {
    Crop.Y -= Dif / 2;                //
    Crop.Height += Dif;               // B
    Dif = Crop.Width * Margin * 2;    // 
}
```

It feels like A & B could be replaced by a function that figured out whether to pick Crops' X & Width, or Crops' Y & Height. The code above works just fine, but I figure that there has to be a prettier way, and I can't find it.

A friend of mine made something, although in Java, using an IntConsumer & lambda functions that managed to simplify A & B into one function that magically works. I don't get it though. :-)

```
private static int squarize(int n, int shortBound, int longBound, IntConsumer locSetter, IntConsumer boundSetter, int dif, int margin) {
    locSetter.accept(n - dif / 2);
    boundSetter.accept(shortBound + dif);
    return longBound * margin * 2;
}
```

Comment: While it may be possible to do clever things with this, I don't think it would actually make it any simpler or clearer.

Comment: Sometime you just gotta write the code out

Comment: I can think of a way using reflection, but it wouldn't be as clear or as fast as your current code.

Comment: Forgot a bit of the story... Thx for the replies so far, it's what I was thinking as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To answer your question: **"Is it possible, in C#, to simplify this if by generalising the properties somehow?"**:

No, it isn't. Your code is perfectly fine as it is.

Just for completeness, you *could* do it like this, but to be clear: I don't think this is easier to follow than the original code. It's just "clever".

```
if (Crop.Width < Crop.Height)
    (Crop.X, Crop.Width,  Dif) = (Crop.X - Dif / 2, Crop.Width  + Dif, Crop.Height * Margin * 2);
else
    (Crop.Y, Crop.Height, Dif) = (Crop.Y - Dif / 2, Crop.Height + Dif, Crop.Width  * Margin * 2);
```

Beauty is in the eye of the beholder, so it's up to you if this is "Prettier". ;)

I much prefer the original.

Comment: Cool use of ternaries! :-D
I see what you're saying regarding clever. Thank you.

Comment: @JefBracke There are no ternary operators used in this answer.  This is merely using tuples to perform three assignments into one statement.  You could accomplish more or less the same thing by just removing the whitespace in your own code.

Comment: You're right, tuples is what I meant. Thx for pointing it out.